# Parse strings with a regex and store the result in an array or a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help to improve my code :

I am beginner with regex system.

I would like to fecth NUMBER below in script and store it in a string or an array to moment that output "*NUMBER1*,NUMBER1_NUMBER2_,NUMBER2" I don't understand why, i would like jsut NUMBER at the end ;

```
function fetchnumber(){
    extract = "";
    for(picture = 1 ; picture < 5; picture++){

 // get background image as a string as this :

 // url('http://www.mywebsite.com/directory/image_NUMBER_.png');

       var NumberOfPicture = document.getElementById(picture).style.backgroundImage ;


       reg = /\_(.*)\_/;
         extract += reg.exec(NumberOfPicture);


       }
     }
```

Comment: What is the result with what you have now? Are there console errors? Read the documentation for `RegExp.exec` to start with. What does it return? Also, make sure your IDs are really 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this small example for you. Hope this help you.

```
var inputString = 'http://www.mywebsite.com/directory/image_123_.png';
var imageNumber = (/image_([^_]+)_\.\w{3}$/.exec(inputString) || [,false])[1];
// so into imageNumber variable you will have a 123 or false if there is no mach
if (imageNumber) {
   // here you can do something with finded 
   // part of text. 
}
```

I wish you luck with the implementation.

You asked why there is [1] instead [0]. The explanation is that we need to have 
the same behavior when there is no match of regex. This is quote from MDN

> The exec() method executes a search for a match in a specified string.
>   Returns a result array, or null.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec

So. If there is match for regular expression the returned array will consist
from matched string located at zero index ([0]) and with first backreference at first index [1] back references are symbols between brackets (sddsd).  But if there is no match we will pass [,false] as output so we will expect the result 
into first array index [1]. Try the code with different input. For example:

```
var inputString = 'some text some text ';
var imageNumber = (/image_([^_]+)_\.\w{3}$/.exec(inputString) || [,false])[1];
// so into imageNumber variable you will have a 123 or false if there is no mach
if (imageNumber) {
   // here you can do something with finded 
   // part of text. 
}
```

So .. In this case the condition will not be executed at all. I mean:

```
if (imageNumber) {
   // here you can do something with finded 
   // part of text. 
}
```

Comment: that work thank but i have a ask why [1] and not [0]?

Comment: Thanks to your answer.